# Bitcoin transaction cpp

Tags: bitcoin-core

can anyone help me with the code to get transaction info of a block of bitcoin.
I have tried to extract the transaction using postman but did not come through properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python to get transaction data of block you will need to import requests library so first add that "requests" library to your project then run following code

```
import requests
block_hash = '0000000000000bae09a7a393a8acded75aa67e46cb81f7acaa5ad94f9eacd103'
api_url_base = 'https://blockchain.info/rawblock/'
api_url = api_url_base + block_hash
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
jsondata = response.json()
trasactiondata = jsondata['tx']
print(trasactiondata)
```

if you are using the multiple blocks then run this code in for loop and in each iteration change the block_hash value there you have to put block hash value and this code will give you all transaction data of that block